# Crash in TextInput - how to debug?

Tags: ios, crash

I'm getting crash reports for my iOS app with the following or similar stack in the crashed thread:

```
0   TextInput                           0x0003149a TIInputManager::apply_case_changes_to_result(std::vector >&, KB::Hashmap const&, std::vector > const&) const + 402
1   TextInput                           0x00030bf3 TIInputManager::lookup() + 863
2   TextInput                           0x000307ad TIInputManager::autocorrection() + 61
3   TextInput                           0x00042d21 -[TIKeyboardInputManagerZephyr autocorrection] + 137
4   UIKit                               0x0011a319 -[UIKeyboardImpl generateCandidatesWithOptions:] + 377
5   UIKit                               0x00133071 -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:fromVariantKey:] + 2597
6   UIKit                               0x00130f8d -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 1453
7   UIKit                               0x001308b7 -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar sendStringAction:forKey:isPopupVariant:] + 487
8   UIKit                               0x0012f3ad -[UIKeyboardLayoutStar touchUp:] + 3101
9   UIKit                               0x0012e737 -[UIKeyboardLayout touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 387
10  UIKit                               0x000165f9 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 525
11  UIKit                               0x00003809 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 381
12  UIKit                               0x00003123 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6155
13  GraphicsServices                    0x000065a3 _PurpleEventCallback + 591
14  GraphicsServices                    0x000061d3 PurpleEventCallback + 35
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00097173 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00097117 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 139
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00095f99 __CFRunLoopRun + 1385
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00008ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00008d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
20  GraphicsServices                    0x000052eb GSEventRunModal + 75
21  UIKit                               0x00057301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
22  MyApp                               0x0000294b main (main.mm:8)
```

Only the bottom-most line (`main`) is mine. It looks like the crash is somewhere in an touch up event handler within the text input framework, and it has to do with autocorrect.

Those crashes come with disheartening consistency - this looks like a subtle bug of mine, not that of iOS itself. The call stack is inconsistent - sometimes it ends in UIKit, sometimes in libobjc. The iOS version, however, seems to be consistently 6.x.

Any idea how to debug this, please?

EDIT: SIGSEGV/SEGV_ACCERR in thread 0. The error address varies - sometimes, it's zero, sometimes not.

Comment: have you found the solution to this problem? Same thing here.

Comment: Me too, at a dead end.

Comment: How do you implement the textinput? Where does xcode show an error? have you tried running nszombies? WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED? There is nothing in your question that helps anyone help you. Please be more specific.

Comment: Text box instantiated via a NIB file, pretty vanilla. Xcode does not show an error; this error is delivered to me from users' devices via a live crash reporting service (QuincyKit/PLCrashReporter). If there was a clear path to debugging or at least reproducing this, I won't be asking the question.

Comment: Is there an exception? EXC_BAD_ACCESS? The stack trace is unhelpful if we don't know the actual error being thrown.

Comment: What is TIInputManager? Are you using a framework?

Comment: No third party frameworks (except PLCrashReporter), all vanilla iOS SDK.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. Can't figure it out as well :(

Comment: Did you add Exception Breakpoint from Breakpoint Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an error with Apple. Go into your Settings on the simulator (the Settings app on the sim, that is) and turn off auto correction.

Comment: This is happening on user devices, not on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same on iOS 6.1.3 (twice) and 6.1.4 (once), all in the field reported as crashlogs. All seem to be nil pointer dereferences deep within Apple's C++ code for . I don't think that there is anything that we can do beyond filing a bug report with Apple (I've raised one listed as: 15573020). Apple treat duplicate reports as an indicator of prioritisation of bugs so if you have suffered I suggest that you add a report at https://bugreport.apple.com and reference the report I have provided.